# Tweets captured with twitterR generate codification error in data.frame

Tags: json, r, twitter

I have a file with tweets captured with twitteR library

```
library("stringi")
library("rjson")


json_data <- lapply(readLines("tweets.json",-1L, warn=FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8"), function(x) fromJSON(x, unexpected.escape = "skip"))
text <- sapply(json_data, function(x) x$text)
df <- data.frame(text)
summary(df)
```

Generates this error:

```
Error in data.frame("RT @ (.....)  \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb4\xa5\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xa5 https://",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

How I can skip this error?

Comment: you need to share the data that causes the error

Comment: It looks like your `text` list is not even close to being something that could be converted into a `data.frame`. It needs to be a list of vectors of the same length. I am afraid you will not be able to "skip this error"

Comment: You could give us the output of `str(text)`, that would help diagnose it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that exist various attributes called "text" because a tweet can be replyed, RT etc and in the same tweet stores all information about tweet, RT etc